# Difference between git remote add and git clone

Tags: git, git-clone, git-remote

What does the `clone` command do? Is there any equivalent to it in svn?

What is the difference between

```
git remote add test git://github.com/user/test.git
```

And

```
git clone git://github.com/user/test.git
```

Does the name of the created repo matter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between clone and mkdir->cd->init->remote-add->pull?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108778/what-is-the-difference-between-clone-and-mkdir-cd-init-remote-add-pull)

Comment: The duplicate I chose is kind of a superset of your question: it asks "what's the difference betweeen `git remote add; ...other commands...` and `git clone`.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

`git remote add` just creates an entry in your git config that specifies a name for a particular URL. You must have an existing git repo to use this.

`git clone` creates a new git repository by copying an existing one located at the URI you specify.

Comment: You mean that, for example, in my example, test folder will be empty and I will have to do '$git fetch test' from test folder?

Comment: @nacho4d: You'd have to do `git init` first, then `git fetch` and `git merge` (or `git pull`) afterwards, and then you'd still be a little bit off... see the duplicate I linked.

Answer (score 62):

These are functionally similar (try it!):

```
 # git clone REMOTEURL foo
```

and:

```
 # mkdir foo
 # cd foo
 # git init
 # git remote add origin REMOTEURL
 # git pull origin master
 # cd ..
```

Now there are minor differences, but fundamentally you probably won't notice them.  As an exercise left to the reader, compare the .git/config's from each directory.

Comment: I have tried it. With using `clone`, the .git/config has a [branch "master"] part. Does this mean that when using `clone` (In the future) I can merge that branch and with `remote add` I cannot?

Comment: Well, first...  they're still the same.  You can actually merge from the upstream either way.  With the extra "branch" statement in there it means you don't need to specify the upstream branch.  IE, in a clone with the above "branch" in it you can do a "git pull" where as in the other you most likely need to do a "git pull origin master".  Now, you can actually use the "git remote add" with the -t flag too to add this branch statement.  Try a "git remote add" with and without "-t master" :-)

Comment: @nacho4d: You can get that same [branch "master"] section in .git/config, with this command: `git branch --set-upstream master origin/master`. That's the 3rd command I use after the `git remote add` and `git pull` you have listed, and those 3 commands seem to give me an identical configuration to what `git clone` would have done.

Comment: `--set-upstream` seems to be deprecated, this works better: `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master`

Comment: I hate it when developers take the easy options away from you.  IMHO, both pull and push should have the easier --set-upstream flag.

Comment: Actually, if the remote repo does NOT have a master branch, `git clone` works correctly, but `git remote add` runs into a problem because `git init` creates a master branch by default which doesn't correspond to anything in the remote.

Comment: I believe the latter should have a `cd ..` afterwards?

Comment: @Pharap fair enough.  Added.

Answer (score 12):

**`git clone`:**

Will physically download the files into your computer. It will take space from your computer. If the repo is 200Mb, then it will download that all and place it in the directory you cloned.

**`git remote add`:**

Won't take space! It's more like a pointer! It doesn't increase your disk consumption. It just gets a snapshot of what branches are available and their git commit history I believe. It doesn't contain the actual file/folders of your project.

If you do:

```
git remote add TechLeadRepo  git://github.com/user/test.git
```

then you haven't added anything to your computer. After you've added it in your remote branches then you're able to get a list of all branches on that remote by doing:

```
git fetch --all
```

upon fetching (or pulling), you download the files And then if you wanted to do get your colleague's feature22 branch into your local, you'd just do

```
git checkout -b myLocalFeature22 TechLeadRepo/feature22
```

Had you cloned his repo then you would have to go into that local repository's directory and simply just `checkout` to your desired branch

Answer (score 11):

The `clone` command creates a local copy of the repo you specified. `remote add` adds a remote repo that you can either push to or pull from.

The svn equivalent of `clone` is `checkout`.

Answer (score 0):

`git clone URL` -

Will physically download the files into your computer. It will take space
from your computer. If the repo is 200 MB, then it will download that all
and place it in the directory you cloned.

`git remote add origin` -

Won't take space! It's more like a pointer! It doesn't increase your disk
consumption. It just gets a snapshot of what branches are available and their
git commit history I believe. It doesn't contain the actual files/folders
of your project.