# What are the differences between "git clone" and "git remote add"?

Tags: git

These two seem to be equivalent:

```
git clone <remote-url> .
git pull

git remote add origin <remote-url>
git pull origin master
```

What are the differences?

Comment: These aren't equivalent; the first creates a local Git repo; the second doesn't (you already need to be in one).

Answer (score 0):

`git remote add origin` just creates an entry in your git config that specifies a name for a particular URL. You must have an existing git repo to use this.

`git clone` creates a new git repository by copying an existing one located at the URI you specify.

Duplicate: [Difference between git remote add and git clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855561/difference-between-git-remote-add-and-git-clone)

Comment: If you found a duplicate, then please remember to flag this question as such as well, perhaps even leaving a comment.

Answer (score 0):

With `git clone` you clone a complete repository, meaning, that you do not need to make any preparations.

With `git remote add origin` you add a remote repository to your existing repository. That means, there has to be an existing repository in the directory, you are currently in.

For the differences between `git pull` commands, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797183/differences-between-git-pull-commands-when-pulling-from-origin)